# Does there exist a closed form?

Tags: summation

I wish to find a closed form for $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}$. does it exist? If so, what is it?

I cannot arrive at one using any methods I am aware of.

Comment: It's called the $n$-th harmonic number, $\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{i} = H_n$. Not really a closed form, but the asymptotics are known pretty well.

Comment: Any approximations?

Comment: $H_n = \log \bigl(n+\frac{1}{2}\bigr) + \gamma + O(n^{-2})$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

Comment: As $n$ becomes large, your limit becomes $\ln n + \gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the Euler constant, and $\ln n$ is natural logarithm. I don't know if it's proved that no closed form exists, but at least, no simple closed form is known.

Comment: DOES this have a closed form and no one has found it yet, or is it known that it does not have a closed form solution?

Comment: @RaceBannon Notion of "closed form" is highly informal one, and there is no standard definition for that. This makes it impossible to argue that it does not have a closed form.

Comment: @wojowu what about if we call closed form to an expression for which the amount of operations to compute the result doesn't depend of the argument of the expression?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD So $n!$ has no closed form?

Answer (score 0):

The following could be called a closed form in absence of a better answer. Define
$$e_k(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k\leq n}{x_{i_1}x_{i_2}\cdots x_{i_k}}$$
This is the $k$th elementary symmetric polynomial in $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$. Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1}{i}}=\frac{e_{n-1}(1,2,3,\ldots,n)}{n!}$$
We can see this by taking a common denominator. Of course, the denominator $n!$ will not generally be as small as possible. For example,
$$\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3+1\cdot 2\cdot 4+1\cdot 3\cdot 4+2\cdot 3\cdot 4}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4}=\frac{50}{24}=\frac{25}{12}$$